# AFRAME: How to use Three's render property setPixelRatio on A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe

[Three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setPixelRatio) has a renderer property setPixelRatio that I would like to use set to 2.

Reviewing the [A-Frame docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/renderer.html), I don't see a corresponding property.

Does anyone know a way to implement it into an A-Frame project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a custom component.  Just add this to your head (or put this in a separate JS file, and reference that).

```
    <script>
      AFRAME.registerComponent('pixel-ratio', {
        schema: {
          type: 'number'
        },
        update: function() {
           this.el.sceneEl.renderer.setPixelRatio(this.data)
        }
      })
    </script>
```

and then declare your `<a-scene>` like this:

```
<a-scene pixel-ratio="2">
</a-scene>
```

In the Three.js docs, I don't see any restrictions on when setPixelRation can be called, so this should work fine.

You can also adjust pixel ratio at any time by changing the `pixel-ratio` attribute on the `a-scene`

Example on glitch here:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/set-pixel-ratio